# Can I add more than one instance to a plane using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I added my grass using *Geometry Nodes*, and now I want to add my flowers as well. I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. When I select the flower to place on my "grass" it does not show up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The input is missing... Simply connect your existing grid to the "Mesh" input of the `Distribute Points on Faces` node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several possibilities to achieve this.

In all cases, however, it is important that you also give the node `Distribute Points on Faces` a mesh on whose faces the points are to be distributed.

1. You can use the same mesh as often as you want:

   [image]
2. You can also separate the points created on the faces into two groups and then instantiate on them:

   [image]
   <sub>(Here I control the distribution between grass and flowers with the node `Random Value`)</sub>
3. Or you can also use multiple objects from a collection for this, and use the *Pick Instance* and *Instance Index* option to control the distribution:

   [image]
   <sub>(Here I control the distribution between grass and flowers also with the node `Random Value` and use their values as *Instance Index*)</sub>

*PS: For all three examples there are a lot of answers here on blender.stackexchange.com. Please use the [search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D%20Distribute%20Points%20on%20Faces) to find the right example for you.*

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it out last night that I didn’t have it connected to the mesh.